# how can i open files on shared intranet drives from winforms.core app?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

EDIT:
I got it to work by deploying my app. The problem only existed when i was running in debug mode in visual studio.

I am creating an application that holds a lot paths for easy access.

```
            var item = this.CockpitLinkDataTable.Rows[this.CockPitLinkDataTable.CurrentCell.RowIndex];
    
            var tableRow = (Link)item.DataBoundItem;
            new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo($@"{tableRow.LinkPath}")
                {
                    UseShellExecute = true
                }
            }.Start();
```

the code works fine when i try to open local files or webpages.
When i try to open files from intranet shared drives i get the error message: "The system cannot find the drive specified."

But if i copy the path an run it in windows.run it opens perfectly fine.

Comment: what format are you providing the paths to the application? Is it `\\server\share` (i.e. UNC) format, or something else?

Comment: okay so i figured it out, apparently it didnt work when the app were run in debug mode from visual studio. After i deployed the app on my machine its working. I suspect it might be something about windows authentication .

Comment: and to answer you question my path i used was: "M:\path"

Comment: Then it's possible that the account under which the code was running in debug mode doesn't have that drive mapped. Better to use UNC share names if possible

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code to open files from the shared internet drives.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool status = false;

            //connect to the shared folder use ip address ,username and password
            status = connectState(@"\\1xx.xx.xx.xx\share", "username", "password");
            if (status)
            {
                DirectoryInfo theFolder = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\1xx.xx.xx.xx\Share\Huan");
                var fileInfo = theFolder.GetFiles("*.txt").First().FullName;  //get the path
                var text = File.ReadAllLines(fileInfo); //read the txt file
            }
           
        }
    public bool connectState(string path)
    {
        return connectState(path, "", "");
    }
    public  bool connectState(string path, string userName, string passWord)
    {
        bool Flag = false;
        Process proc = new Process();
        try
        {
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc.Start();
            string dosLine = "net use " + path + " " + passWord + " /user:" + userName;
            proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(dosLine);
            proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
            while (!proc.HasExited)
            {
                proc.WaitForExit(1000);
            }
            string errormsg = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            proc.StandardError.Close();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(errormsg))
            {
                Flag = true;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(errormsg);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            proc.Close();
            proc.Dispose();
        }
        return Flag;
    }
```

Update:
Direct way:

```
 DirectoryInfo theFolder = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\1xx.xx.xx.xx\Share\Huan");
 var fileInfo = theFolder.GetFiles("*.txt").First().FullName;  //get the path
 var text = File.ReadAllLines(fileInfo); //read the txt file
```

Comment: I kinda want to use a solution without the need of passwords and all that stuff. But as i mentioned in my EDIT i got it to work. The reason is my debug session dont have the same rights as my active directory user.

Comment: @TheNillesen, I used connectState method to check if the user can connect the shared drive. If you have the permission to the files, you can access the file use the path '\\1xx.xx.xx.xx\Share\Huan\test.txt' directly.